# Aiogram bot отправка изображения после редактирования в PIL

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import CommandHelp
from aiogram.types import Message
from loader import dp, bot
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
 

font = ImageFont.truetype('img/mon.ttf', size=24)


def picture_cert():
    img = Image.open(f"img/sert-1.png")
    draw_text = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw_text.text((12,170), '1.Меллиса White', fill=('#FFFFFF'), font=font)
    draw_text.text((44,205), '2.Меллиса White', fill=('#FFFFFF'), font=font)

    return img

@dp.message_handler(CommandHelp())
async def show_menu(message: Message):
    img = picture_cert()
    #img = BytesIO(photo)
    await message.answer_photo(img)
```

выдает такую ошибку

```
TypeError: Can not serialize value type: <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
 headers: {}
 value: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=512x366 at 0x27CB164ADF0>
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает, какая ошибка?

Comment: вот написал ошибку